# How to calculate 64-bit hash on 32 bit platform in C++?

Tags: c++

As far as I see std::hash calculates the hash of type size_t, but I need to calculate the hash of type uint64_t independently of whether the app is 32 or 64 bit to write it to file and read in another app, for example.

Is it possible with standard C++ library?

To make the question more clear:

```
std::hash<std::string> h1;
std::hash<std::vector<bool>> h2;
std::hash<int> h3;
```

all h1(), h2(), h3() are of type size_t, but I need uint64_t.

Comment: Why are you using `std::hash` instead of a hashing method that meets whatever requirements you need? You can implement your own if necessary. To avoid XY Problems why are you doing this? Values from `std::hash` are only useful for a narrow set of situations, like `std::map` distributions.

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: longs tend to be 64 bits, just in case, the 32 or 64 of OSs are related to memory address size

Comment: @gia `long long` maybe.

Comment: @gia That is normally just 64 bit nix systems that does that.

Comment: yes, long long, should really learn from sql and do stuff like int(64)

Comment: You are going to have to write your own or find a library if you always want the hash to be a `uint64_t`.

Comment: @tadman I need to protect a file from corruption by hashing the data blocks and my idea was to save the time (my time) by using std::hash. What can be wrong with it?

Comment: @NeilButterworth I need to protect a file from corruption by hashing the data blocks

Comment: @NathanOliver why not to have a template function specialization that combines two std::hash-es on 32 bit platform to calculate 64 bit hash?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky Most likely that wouldn't be the same value if you switch to a 64 bit platform.  Can you share why the hash need to be 64 bits wide on a 32 bit system?

Comment: @NathanOliver I wonted to save it to a file in 64 bit format. But...

Comment: These hashes aren't intended to detect bit-flip errors, they're just intended to be deterministically random. For data errors consider something like CRC for the most basic case or SHA2-256 for more accurate detection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard library does not impose specific algorithms for calculating hashes, so you won't get portable hash codes from the standard library, even for the same system, if you use a different compiler. So you'll just have to write your own.